# What's the EPNdB for large turbofan engines for stage 5 noise regulations?

Tags: faa-regulations, engine, noise

I'm trying to estimate the [Effective Perceived Noise](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/EnvironmentalWorkshops/Documents/Noise-Certification-Workshop-2006/Depitre_4.pdf) (EPNdB) of the [GE9x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90). GE Aviation says that it will be within 8 dB margin of the [stage 5 noise regulations](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/noise_emissions/airport_aircraft_noise_issues/levels/), can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 4):

What the FAA is calling "Stage 5" is the ICAO Chapter 14 regulations. These do no go into effect until 2017 or 2020, but that means it would be applicable for future engines such as the GE9X.

The cumulative EPNdB margin for Chapter 14 is Chapter 4 +7, or Chapter 3 +17. The exact EPNdB value [depends on takeoff weight](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/Green/Documents/day%201pdf/session%202/2-Dickson.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I found document to be helpful as well. http://www.icao.int/Meetings/Green/Documents/day%201pdf/session%202/2-Dickson.pdf